# Is the Classic xtype: 'pagingtoolbar' available in Modern

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect 4.3 Beta with SDK 7.4,CMD 7.4 Modern framework.
This [Kitchen Sink](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/examples/kitchensink/#paging-grid) shows the Classic Ext.grid.Panel and xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'.

This [kitchen sink](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/examples/kitchensink/#sliding-pager) shows the Modern
xtype: 'grid' with the 'gridpagingtoolbar' which I find really does not work well for large data sets.

Is there an equivalent of the Classic pagingtoolbar in Modern?

Comment: Your link leads to the classic kitchen sink, have a look into the modern one and what you might want is probably change the content of the bottom toolbar (sliderfield) to something which fits for your needs (looks like the classic one). I doubt this can become hard using architekt.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have amended my question accordingly.